# Extraction Of Face From a Bitmap

Tags: android, image, image-processing, bitmap

After being given suggestions to use circular crop i implemented it in my application to use to extract face from the bitmap but its too inefficient i mean its of no use and similar to cropping from the rectangular face. Now here is what i have done up til now:

1. Launched Camera
2. Taken Picture
3. Detected The face in the Picture
4. Painting a rectangular window in the area face has been detected

Now the serious issue am facing is getting face from that bitmap. I just want to get the face. Ignore all the other details that were in the face detection window. If it was matlab it could have been too simpler with the help of edge detection techniques and segmentation algorithms and function. I want to know how can i do the same process in android application? plz do share the code snippets if u know of any. This is taking too much of my time and i just want to get over with this face extraction part.

Code i did till now:

```
public class Makeover extends Activity {
private static final int TAKE_PICTURE_CODE = 100;
private static final int MAX_FACES = 5;

private Bitmap cameraBitmap = null;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);

((Button)findViewById(R.id.take_picture)).setOnClickListener(btnClick);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if(TAKE_PICTURE_CODE == requestCode){
                processCameraImage(data);

        }
}

private void openCamera(){
Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

startActivityForResult(intent, TAKE_PICTURE_CODE);
   }

private void processCameraImage(Intent intent){
setContentView(R.layout.detectlayout);

((Button)findViewById(R.id.detect_face)).setOnClickListener(btnClick);

ImageView imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image_view);

cameraBitmap = (Bitmap)intent.getExtras().get("data");

imageView.setImageBitmap(cameraBitmap);
}

private void detectFaces(){
Bitmap bmFace = null;
if(null != cameraBitmap){
        int width = cameraBitmap.getWidth();
        int height = cameraBitmap.getHeight();

        FaceDetector detector = new FaceDetector(width, height,Makeover.MAX_FACES);
        Face[] faces = new Face[Makeover.MAX_FACES];

        Bitmap bitmap565 = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Config.RGB_565);
        Paint ditherPaint = new Paint();
        Paint drawPaint = new Paint();

        //jo bhi krna hai ab bitmap565 k sath krna hai apse wo image hai main

        ditherPaint.setDither(true);
        drawPaint.setColor(Color.RED);
        drawPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        drawPaint.setStrokeWidth(2);

        Canvas canvas = new Canvas();
        canvas.setBitmap(bitmap565);
        canvas.drawBitmap(cameraBitmap, 0, 0, ditherPaint);

        int facesFound = detector.findFaces(bitmap565, faces);
        PointF midPoint = new PointF();
        float eyeDistance = 0.0f;
        float confidence = 0.0f;

        Log.i("FaceDetector", "Number of faces found: " + facesFound);

        if(facesFound > 0)
        {
                for(int index=0; index<facesFound; ++index){
                        faces[index].getMidPoint(midPoint);
                        eyeDistance = faces[index].eyesDistance();
                        confidence = faces[index].confidence();

                        Log.i("FaceDetector", 
                                        "Confidence: " + confidence + 
                                        ", Eye distance: " + eyeDistance + 
                                        ", Mid Point: (" + midPoint.x + ", " + midPoint.y + ")");

                        canvas.drawRect((int)midPoint.x - eyeDistance , 
                                                        (int)midPoint.y - eyeDistance , 
                                                        (int)midPoint.x + eyeDistance, 
                                                        (int)midPoint.y + eyeDistance, drawPaint);
                }
        }

        for(int count=0;count<detector.findFaces(bitmap565, faces);count++)
        {
            float left;
            float top;
            PointF midPoints=new PointF();
            faces[count].getMidPoint(midPoint);         
            eyeDistance=faces[count].eyesDistance();

            left = midPoint.x - (float)(1.4 * eyeDistance);
            top = midPoint.y - (float)(1.8 * eyeDistance);

            bmFace = Bitmap.createBitmap(cameraBitmap, (int) left, (int) top, (int) (2.8 * eyeDistance), (int) (3.6 * eyeDistance));          
        }


        String filepath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/facedetect" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg";

                try {
                        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(filepath);

                        bitmap565.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, fos);

                        fos.flush();
                        fos.close();
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                }             
                ImageView imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image_view);

                imageView.setImageBitmap(bmFace);
    }
}

private View.OnClickListener btnClick = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
                switch(v.getId()){
                        case R.id.take_picture:         openCamera();   break;
                        case R.id.detect_face:          detectFaces();  break;  
                }
        }
};
}
```

Comment: very tough.. matlab is very much different then android. matlab has inbuilt facility to work with images. I think you should go for OpenCV.

Comment: ahhhh the natice code is such a bad thing to work with :(

Comment: ha ha...lolz...I was searching for your solution but some where i got this answer. I also had stuck with OpenCV in image comparison though my matlab colleague has very short of code to image comparison. one more time lolzz...

Comment: i found a bombastic edge detection code in openCV. Works like a charm :D

Comment: again ahhhh though its in native code *sigh* solutions perfect though :p

Comment: can you send me a link for future work .. :D  you can also post your answer and accept it so that other users get benefit of it from your tremendous work..